# Twilio TTS directly to AIFF or MP3?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, text-to-speech, twilio

I would like to  some speech from Twilio directly to an MP3 or AIFF, etc.  Hitherto I've been using a loopback on Mac OS X, which is kind of a pain in the rear as I generally have to use Skype and set a few things up to preform the recordings.

**So, I'm looking for a way, without any quality degradation, to go from the Twilio text-to-speech right to an audio file output for download if at all possible.  Any ideas?**

Comment: you could maybe hack this together using an outbound call with Record=true enabled but it would be pretty wonky.

Comment: Still would be lossy quality though right, since it's going to go over a voip conn I would guess.

Comment: i've never tried so i don't know for sure, but the recording all happens on the same side of the call. the system is just not designed to be a generic TTS engine. what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: My main goal is to convert a number of texts to speech to sound identical as to how they will hear them from the service.  The problem is that the Skype method for recording the calls is a bit burdensome and lossy.

Answer (score 0):

Rob from Twilio here.

Thanks for providing some more color on your attempt to record output from the Twilio Say Verb (aka text-to-speech).  If you are just looking for some high quality recording of computerized voice there are a few easier options available like [TTS-API](http://tts-api.com/) or [iSpeech](https://www.ispeech.org/developers).

But, if you are looking for a quick hack to hear exactly what your users will hear losslessly from your Say verbs, here's one method leveraging [the parameter `Record=true`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

**Step 1**
Create a TwiML document that with a `<Say>` verb of the text you are trying to capture.

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">I am totally going to capture this text in a robot voice.</Say>
</Response>
```

Be sure to host this document in a publicly accessible place (e.g. [a twimlbin like this](http://twimlbin.com/a064bbcf)).

**Step 2**
Create an endpoint to capture the RecordingUrl that Twilio will give you.  Here's one quick example of a Python [Flask app](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that logs a received RecordingUrl.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/recordingHandler', methods=['POST'])
def recording_handler():
    if request.form.get('RecordingUrl'):
        app.logger.info("New recording: %s" % request.form['RecordingUrl'])
    return "Recording Url logged."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**Step 3**
Create a call to your phone executing that TwiML document set to record.  Here's an example in Python.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

ACCOUNT_SID = "ACxxxxxxxxxx"
AUTH_TOKEN = "yyyyyyyyyyyyy"
client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

client.calls.create(from_="[INSERT TWILIO PHONE NUMBER]",
    to="[INSERT YOUR PHONE NUMBER]",
    url="[LINK TO TWIML DOCUMENT IN STEP 1]",
    status_callback="[LINK TO RECORDING HANDLER IN STEP 2]")
```

**Step 4**
Answer the incoming call, listen to the TTS and allow the call to hang itself up.  Then check the output of the handler you created in Step 2 for a link to your crystal clear mp3.

Obviously, this is a bit of a hack to get what you are looking for and there are much easier, cheaper and higher fidelity ways of synthesizing speech than using Twilio.  But, with some creative wrangling of the optional parameters when [creating a call using the Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon), the files you are looking for can absolutely be generated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: TTS-API has been down (at least the part which hosts MP3 files) for several days - hope it's not permanently dead.